# Higher broker latency on apache kafka 2.4 when upgrading from 2.3

Tags: apache-kafka

That is pretty old issue, but decided to share it anyway, maybe someone is still facing that.

Tests done on a vanilla 3 node cluster. Decent CPU, 64G RAM, SSD drive.

When running `kafka-producer-perf-test.sh` like below:

```
$ ./kafka-producer-perf-test.sh --topic test_topic --throughput 30000 --num-records 3000000 --record-size 1024 --producer-props acks=all bootstrap.servers=server1:9092,server2:9092,server3:9092
```

on kafka 2.3.1 I can see the following results (summary line of the above command):

```
3000000 records sent, 29996.700363 records/sec (29.29 MB/sec), 8.52 ms avg latency, 292.00 ms max latency, 5 ms 50th, 9 ms 95th, 86 ms 99th, 229 ms 99.9th.
```

where I focus on the average latency, which is 8.52 ms here.

Now, repeating the same test on kafka 2.5.1 gives much higher scores

```
3000000 records sent, 27373.261798 records/sec (26.73 MB/sec), 962.79 ms avg latency, 3993.00 ms max latency, 6 ms 50th, 10 ms 95th, 128 ms 99th, 251 ms 99.9th.
```

So the average latency increased from 8.52 ms to 962.79 ms which is something that I would not expected to see.

Answer (score 1):

Repeating the same performance stress test on various versions gave me the following results.

| version | latency spike |
| --- | --- |
| 2.3.1 | no |
| 2.4.0 | yes |
| 2.4.1 | yes |
| 2.5.0 | yes |
| 2.5.1 | yes |
| 2.6.0 | no |
| 2.6.1 | no |
| 2.6.2 | no |
| 2.6.3 | no |
| 2.7.0 | no |
| 2.7.1 | no |
| 2.7.2 | no |
| 2.8.0 | no |
| 2.8.1 | no |

As a result we skipped the upgrade to 2.4.1 as was initially planned and went straight to 2.6.3. Looks a bit like a bug, but honestly could not find anything about that.